# How to replace single quotes to double quotes in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

i have a following string:

```
 {"name":"ram","details":[{'subjects':{'service_location':'c:/A.exe','url':'http://A.zip'}}]}
```

In the above string few strings have single quotes around them. so, how can i replace single quotes with double quotes in the above string and get as follows:

```
 {"name":"ram","details":[{"subjects":{"service_location":"c:/A.exe","url":"http://A.zip"}}]}
```

Comment: You have to assume that none of the single quotes in the string are *part* of a value, such as `{"name": "Jake 'The Snake' Jones", "name": 'Bob' }`; otherwise, you won't in general be able to tell (without a more complex parser) which single quotes to replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending @RavinderSingh13 answer, use following command to convert your string.

```
echo '{"name":"ram","details":'"[{'subjects':{'service_location':'c:/A.exe','url':'http://A.zip'}}]}" | sed "s/'/\"/g"
```

Answer (score 7):

@Learner: Try a `sed` solution:

```
sed "s/'/\"/g"  Input_file
```

OR

```
your_command | sed "s/'/\"/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tr` to translate individual characters:

```
your_command | tr "'" '"'
```

Or, if that is too much typing:

```
your_command | tr \' \"
```

:-)

Comment: Put whatever conmand you used to generate the data in place of `your_command` or use `tr \' \" <<< "$your_variable"` if you have it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Following will convert all the single quotes to double quotes. This used `awk`'s inbuilt `gsub` function to search and replace the text. Here, we are telling awk to replace `s` which is equal to single quotes. Once single quote is found replace it with double quote. 1 is to print the line.

```
awk -v s="'" '{gsub(s,"\"")}1' file
```

OR

```
source-of-json | awk -v s="'" '{gsub(s,"\"")}1'
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more like how will i use above in my context  and echo the resulting string