# cd does not work with a variabe that has a variable which has a path

Tags: linux, bash, cd

A minimal example of my problem is

```bash
$ dir='$HOME'
$ cd "$dir" # Not what I want
bash: cd: $HOME: No such file or directory
$ cd $HOME # Works
```

This is used in another script, where `$HOME` is output from `sed`. So I cannot just change dir to `"$HOME"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: The question is more about how to convert from single quotes to double quoted string.

Comment: Use `cd "$HOME"` or `cd ~` or `cd`.

Comment: Please see the note in the end.

Comment: how about something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001148/how-to-replace-single-quotes-to-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: I think that what I need is a way to expand the string.

Comment: Building commands in strings is inherently problematic, see [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) You'd be better off refactoring this to build the command in an array, or just store each piece of data in a separate variable and just use them all as parameters (each in double-quotes) to a regular non-stored command.

Comment: The fundamental problem (revealed in the now-deleted code) was replacing `~` with the literal string `$HOME` in the `dir` variable.  The problem goes away if you replace `~` with the value of `$HOME`.  It's tricky to do that completely safely with `sed`, but one safe way to do it is: `dir=${dir/#~/"$HOME"}`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using `eval`.
I have to use

```
$ eval cd '$HOME'
```

Comment: Noooo! As cyrus mentioned 18 hrs ago, Use `cd "$HOME"` or `cd ~` or `cd`. Continue to use `eval` to solve these sort of problem and ".... You'll Be SORRY!!!!" . Good luck?

Comment: It is in a variable. So what I need is a way to expand a string. Any way to do that?

Comment: In your code, I see `cd $dir`. Just try `cd "$dir"`. Doesn't that work? If not then read  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the Version information at the top and search for the sections  labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question". Then edit your question to show a mimimal version of what is failing you. (Maybe put it at the top in a TLDR section ). Add a comment that you have made this change to the question and commenters will look at it. Good luck.

Comment: Another bit of advice. Recall that variables can hold what ever data type is appropriate for the surrounding coding eco-system. In this case, the coding system is `bash`. In bash, all variables are essentially strings. (You can store a number in a string) (Yes, you can declare variables to only hold number values. That is more advanced and doesn't seem to be an issue for you). You declare a variable with a string value, `var="myString". .....

Comment: To "use" the variable, you add it to a command that is being executed. `ls -l "$var"`. To see what the value IS, you only need to print it, `echo "The value of my \$var=$var"`. Try to use correct terminology in your questions. (-; Good  luck!

Comment: See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).